# jquery mobile navbar add unknown button

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, navbar

I have search for this problem for over 2 hours and i dont understand why something so simple doesn't work.

I try to implement a navbar in my footer but i dont know why jquery add some buttons and the layout becomes horrible.

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>VeryGoodTrip</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>   
</head> 
<body>  
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Destinations</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/corse.png" />
                    <h3>Corse</h3>
                    <p>Corse</p>

                </a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/golf.png" />
                    <h3>Golf du Lyon</h3>
                    <p>Golf du Lyon</p>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/lerins.png" />

                    <h3>Iles de lerins</h3>
                    <p>Iles de lerins</p>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/menton.png" />
                    <h3>Menton</h3>
                    <p>Menton</p>

                </a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/monaco.png" />
                    <h3>Monaco</h3>
                    <p>Monaco</p>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/nice.png" />      
                    <h3>Nice</h3>
                    <p>Nice</p>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/tropez.png" />
                    <h3>Saint-Tropez</h3>
                    <p>Saint-Tropez</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">      
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="refresh" class="ui-state-persist ui-btn-active">Destinations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="refresh">Activités</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="refresh">Planning</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

And this is what i get with firebug :

```
<div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed fade ui-fixed-overlay" role="contentinfo" style="top: -155px;">
    <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" data-theme="a">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
            <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <div data-iconpos="right" data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar" role="navigation">
        **<a href="index.html" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-right">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
            </span>
        </a>**
        <ul class="ui-grid-c">
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-block-a ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-a" data-theme="a">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                    <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
                </span>
            </a>
            <li class="ui-block-b">
                <a href="index.html" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-a">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                        <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <a class="ui-state-persist ui-btn-active ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-a" data-icon="refresh" href="index.html" data-theme="a">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                        <span class="ui-btn-text">Destinations</span>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh ui-icon-shadow"></span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-block-c">
                <a data-icon="refresh" href="index.html" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-a">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                        <span class="ui-btn-text">Activit?s</span>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh ui-icon-shadow"></span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-block-d">
                <a data-icon="refresh" href="index.html" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-right">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                        <span class="ui-btn-text">Planning</span>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh ui-icon-shadow"></span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div>
```

As you can see the two following button shouldn't be here any idea ?

```
<a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" data-theme="a">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
<span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
</span>
</a>

<a href="index.html" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-right">
<span class="ui-btn-inner">
    <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
</span>
</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close a `<a>` tag so the HTML elements are not nested properly. The problem is with the last list-item in the `data-role="content` div:

```
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/tropez.png" />
                    <h3>Saint-Tropez</h3>
                    <p>Saint-Tropez</p>
            </li>
```

should be:

```
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/tropez.png" />
                    <h3>Saint-Tropez</h3>
                    <p>Saint-Tropez</p>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Here is a demo of the above fix: http://jsfiddle.net/9q6My/ (I added a comment next to the closing `</a>` tag I added)

As you can see from the code I formatted above, I make sure to indent each nested tag so I can see that every tag has been properly closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was so sure to have checked this. It resolved my issue.

Comment: @Chido42 You're welcome. If you found the answer helpful an Up-Vote would be appreciated or if you found this is the correct answer an Accpted-Answer-Vote would be appreciated.